# Fetch a specific value from Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to be able to get the address and name of the users in firebase, but I just can't find a way to do it.
Here is my best effort. This seems fine in Xcode, but the app crashes when I push the button to retrieve the values ( thread 1 exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0)

```
 ref?.child("users").child(user)
        .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            let userDict = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]

            let address = userDict["Address:"] as! String
            let name = userDict["Name:"] as! String
            print("Address: \(address)  Name: \(name)")})
```

Comment: By using force unwrapping, *you* are telling your app to crash. You should instead safely unwrap/downcast the optionals and handle the possible errors due to values being nil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like @Moritz mentioned in the comment, if you force unwrap (you are telling these values won't be `nil`) and if one of your values turn out to be `nil`, it will crash the app. Try something like this -

```
ref?.child("users").child(user).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
  guard let userDict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any],
    let address = userDict["Address:"] as? String,
    let name = userDict["Name:"] as? String else {
      return
    }

  print("Address: \(address)  Name: \(name)")
})
```

This will not print anything if either of your `Name` or `Address` is `nil`